# Best Practices to update multiple records with a single server request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `User` model which `hasMany` `phones`. The UI for the user allows to add/delete/update phones on the single form.

When user submits the form all changes to the phone list are sent to the server with a single request.

I have extended the `App.UserSerializer` with custom `serializeHasMany` to include all the phone details in the single request.

The real problem is to sync the `store` state after the request is complete.
Basically I need to solve these two problems:

1. Remove deleted records from the store. I could not find any methods which just removes a record from a store.
2. Update new records with the ids generated by server. (Or just remove the new records from the `store` and `hasMany` array since response creates the dups for the added records)

Is there any best practices or work arounds for this kind of scenarios?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice for now is just sticking to regular REST. In your case this will mean a few extra requests (really though, how many phones can a user have?), but it will spare you a lot of effort in handling things manually.

Ember may support bulk updates in the future (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md, *"We plan to support batch saving with a single HTTP request through a dedicated API in the future."*)

Comment: I down-voted because while OP asks specifically about phones - there are lots of users looking for solutions for data-models with much greater pluralities. Sticking to regular REST just doesn't cut it when that's a bulk action with 100+ requests.